# Do resource potions stack?

Tags: clash-of-clans

With regards to the new resource potions in CoC (the ones you can store in your Clan Castle, and applies to all collectors for 1 day) - are they able to be stacked more than once.

e.g. If I activate 2, will my collector efficiency by 4x rather than 2x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they don't stack. They do however last longer. See [here](https://forum.supercell.com/showthread.php/1665541-Does-X2-gem-boost-and-the-resource-potions-stack) for more detail.